# ORA-00904 invalid identifier - can't figure out error

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL dummy here who could really use some help.
I am attempting to sum up the number of records grouped by 2 fields in a set of tables. I can't figure out why I keep getting an invalid identifier error. I know the column names are correct and they exist. What am I doing wrong here?

```
select td.prot_number, td.block_number, count(bi.sn_bid) as num_bids
from timstabs.bids bi
inner join timstabs.tract_descs td
 on td.sn_tracts_fk = bi.sn_tracts_fk
inner join timstabs.leases ls
 on ls.sn_tracts_fk = bi.sn_tracts_fk
where ls.lease_status_cd = 'REJECT'
group by td.prot_number, td.block_number
```

Comment: can you share the table DDLs? Also share the error message as it is.

Comment: It's highly likely you've got a typo somewhere, most likely in a table name. Alternatively you have absolutely no privileges on one of those tables whatsoever. Try to select from each table individually and all the columns in that table that you're using. Do this by copying and pasting from your query rather than relying on your eyesight to check that it's correct (I speak from experience).

Comment: Here's the error from Oracle SQL Developer

    ORA-00904: "BI"."SN_TRACTS_FK": invalid identifier
    00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    Error at Line: 4 Column: 22

Comment: Edit your questions with "desc timstabs.bids" "desc timstabs.tract_descs" "desc "timstabs.leases"

Comment: Do you have a sn_tracts_fk column in timstabs.bids? The database is saying you don't with that error message.

Comment: @KenGaines Learn how to debug!!!  It's part of programmer's job to debug their own code.  Remove all the join, just start with one table.  If working, add a join, then another join, then add where, and group by last.  It's pretty straight forward.